# i need help ethereum didnt send my full amout

Tags: blockchain, ether, metamask, etherscan, ethereumjs

any pls help,i wanted to send FTM {eth} from my meta mask to gate.io and on during the transacton its failed and i have not recieved my token back yet i was only given about 15% of what i sent
it says this :
https://gyazo.com/87ff3751e81debd4bae6515fccd31e59

transaction link is
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x818c20d4d86ab17d55330c7ab848b567c8525acd3787381fda46c8ad27e7817b

someone pls help it was all my money and i dont know what to doo

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to ethereum stackechange. It seems that you made 2 separate transactions trying to send your FTM, the 1st is the one you've linked already, the 2nd is https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeb1d49aba12f1c601da1a8023bbe99fed2f7986119c9341e9ee4f475f26d9667 and went through perfectly fine